# Determining whether an equilibrium solution exists.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the equation

$$mx''+bx'=-mg$$

where $m,g,b >0$

I have to first write this equation as a 1st order differential system then find all its equilibria. So this is what I get;

$$
\begin{cases} 
      x' = y \\
      y' = -\frac{by}{m} - g 
   \end{cases}
$$

Equilibria occur when $x' = y' = 0$

First if $y= 0$ then $0 = -g$ this is nonsense. so we obtain $y = \frac{-mg}{b}$, what is the $x$ coordinate of the equilibrium? surely It cannot be $x =\frac{-mgt}{b}$??

Comment: If that is the case, the system does not have a equilibrium solution since $y$ cannot be $< 0$ and $= 0$

Comment: ah I see!. Thanks.